# VBa : multiple pictures on multiple picturebox

Tags: image, vba, picturebox

hi its a catalogue application
I have 50 pictures on my folder but i want in the app load show 12 pictures in 12 picturebox
i use this code but it gives me nothing

```
 Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

       Dim pic As PictureBox

    For i = 0 To 12
        pic = Me.Controls("picturebox" & i)
        pic.Image = Image.FromFile("C:\Dev\Images\TEST400.jpg")
    Next i



End Sub
```

Help plz

Comment: you have tagged VBA and psoted VB.Net snippet??

Comment: vba.net gave me error

Comment: There is nothing called Vba.Net, yet. We wish there was one but unfortunately not yet.

Comment: For the future, VBA and VB.NET are not the same. So don't tag a VB.NET question with VBA, or vice versa.

Comment: Ok noted thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your image files should be saved as TEST1.jpg,TEST2.jpg, ......TEST12.jpg etc.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

       Dim pic As PictureBox

    For i = 1 To 12
        pic = Me.Controls("picturebox" & i)
        pic.Image = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Dev\Images\TEST" + i.ToString +".jpg")
    Next i



End Sub
```

Note: I just wrote this code here only. Its not tested.

Comment: how can i use picturebox size because i don't have full image?

Comment: pic.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage 
found it thank you again

Comment: @MohamedJalil, Once your question is solved make sure to mark it as answered/upvote.